# Accessing subfolders of a windows share from linux

Tags: linux, windows, samba, network-share

at my work they have a funny setup:

my home folder is a subfolder to a share, as such:

`\\server\share\subfolder`

Now I have full permissions to the subfolder, but no permissions to share.

From windows I can connect to the VPN of my work place, type the above address into any address field, and voila: I see the contents of my home folder.

In Linux (using Ubuntu) however, I can't figure out how to connect directly to the subfolder. Every attempt I can think of keeps returning "Access denied", because I don't have permission to view the share.

Any help on how to connect to the subfolder would be greatly appreciated :)

Cheers,
Born2Smile

Answer (score 2):

On a Debian (almost Ubuntu, probably close enough), I can mount a subdirectory of a share directly like so:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo
$ smbmount '\\cifs.cs.brown.edu\home\jon-test' /tmp/foo -o user=jon-test,dom=cs.brown.edu
```

(For the user "jon-test@CS.BROWN.EDU".)

Then, cd to /tmp/foo, or type that into an address field, or etc. as appropriate to see the files in the share.

When you're done, unmount with

```
$ smbumount /tmp/foo
$ rmdir /tmp/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

try mounting the subfolder directly with the settings in the mount command appropriate to your system and the system the share is on (samba/nfs)